# how to convert a string to a vector of strings

Tags: r, blastula

I have a textfile with many partners who supports products at diefferent servicelevels.

Partner;Email;Telefon;Servicekarte;Unternummer;Fachhandel;Handel
Partner1;info@partner1.de;;9203;1;;product1,product2
Partner2;info@partner2.de,service@partner2.de;0621-12345678,0621-12345678;9225;1;product3;

I read this file with read_delim an put the result in a dataframe "partners". The result for partners[2, "Email"] is info@partner2.de,service@partner2.de.

Now i want to send a mail with blastula to all adresses in partners[2, "Email"]. Blastula needs a variable `to = c("info@partner2.de", "service@partner2.de")` for the recipients.

My question is how to get the variable **to** from **partners[2, "Email"]**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit()` to divide a text string on a particular character. It will return a list of length 1, so to obtain the desired result in a vector you just subset it

```
x <- "info@partner2.de,service@partner2.de"
to <- strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]
to
# [1] "info@partner2.de"    "service@partner2.de"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sub()` for splitting your data:

```
x <- "info@partner2.de,service@partner2.de"
part_two <- sub(".*,", "", x)
part_one <- sub(",.*", "", x)
to <- c(part_one,part_two)
to
# [1] "info@partner2.de"    "service@partner2.de"
```